# Devise nested form, has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

app/models/post.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts
  attr_accessible ... :posts_attributes

...
```

app/models/post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :user

...
```

app/views/post/new

```
<% form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
<%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :username %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :username, :autofocus => true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>



  <%= f.fields_for :posts do |post_fields| %>

        <%= post_fields.label :title %><br />
        <%= post_fields.text_field :title %></div>
...
```

routes.rb

```
resources :posts
```

For one, the form for users to register works.  But the post portion does not show up in the current configuration.  If i switch fields_for :posts to fields_for :post, I get the full form, but upon submission i get the errors "can't mass assign protected attribute".

Now if i add :post to attr_accessible, I get the error "unknown parameter post"

If i were to move this to the user controller, how do I overwrite the default devise controllers?  Would that even matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to define your `attr_accessible` into your `Post` model as well.

app/models/post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :user
  attr_accessible :title

end
```

Please add this to your controller method :

```
resource.posts.build
```

Hope this will help. Thanks

Comment: I have all the attributes of Post in attr_accessible

Comment: I have updated the answer.Try this and let me know, if it works or not.

Comment: I added 
<% resource.posts.build %> to my view and that worked

Answer (score 0):

I added <% resource.posts.build %> before my form and that worked.